# Позиционирование графика

Tags: python, matplotlib

Хочу позиционировать график с расположением рисунка от - 20 до +20  по Y  и от минус 20 до 1000.

Перепробовал множество методов но как то не выходит, именно позиционирование , график от рисовался шикарно (нечетная функция), но из за этой её не четности не выходит её верно от рисовать.

```
x1 = [i for i in range(1000)]
y1 = [((x1[i]+2)/x1[i]) for i in range(1,1000)]
x2 = np.arange(-20, 20)

ax = plt.gca()
# plot X - axis    
ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')
# plot Y - axis    
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k')

 #plt.plot(x2, y1) # так не работает

plt.plot(y1)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я бы не стал устанавливать предел -20 для оси `Y` при максимаьлном значении `3.0` - ~70% графика выделяется для области, в которой нет значений по оси `Y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю следующий подход:

после `plt.plot(y1)`:

```
In [116]: plt.ylim(-max(y1), max(y1))
Out[116]: (-3.0, 3.0)

In [117]: plt.xlim(-max(x1), max(x1))
Out[117]: (-999, 999)

In [118]: plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]